# How to change submit button value in comment from "Post Comment" to "Send"

Tags: customization, comment-form

How to change submit button value in comment from "Post Comment" to "Send"
I have "responsive" theme , I tried to seach files in wp folder but i can't find the html for this form .

Also Is that Possible to change this value (html Attribute) through CSS ?

below is the code of comment.php file

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>

    <?php
    $fields = array(
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'responsive' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
        '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'E-mail', 'responsive' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
        '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'responsive' ) . '</label>' .
        '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
    );

    $defaults = array( 'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ) );

    comment_form( $defaults );
    ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open **comments.php** file inside your theme's folder

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>

<?php
$fields = array(
    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'responsive' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
    'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'E-mail', 'responsive' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
    'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'responsive' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
);

$defaults = array( 'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),'label_submit'=>__('Send') );

comment_form( $defaults );
?>
```

The comment_form() function is responsible to display the comment form.

It's argument is an array.

The $default you see in the code is an array which contains other arrays as it's items.

The 'fields' items takes array for input fields The 'label_submit' is used to change the label for submit button

You can read more at [codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

Comment: i find comment_form but with different implementation , kindly check my code above

Comment: I've edited the above code. Check now.

Comment: Good , worked fine , thanks alot , not only i need to done a task but also I need to understand so could you please clarify the above code please .

Comment: The comment_form() function is responsible to display the comment form.

It's argument is an array. The $default you see in the code is an array which contains other arrays as it's items.

The 'fields' items takes array for input fields
The 'label_submit' is used to change the label for submit button

You can read more at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

Comment: Is that enough ? :D , any way thanks

Comment: I wasn't done writing and I pressed enter. Please read now that I've edited.

Comment: Excellent , Don't know how to thank you.

Comment: This comment explosion is due to dumping of code without proper explanation. File an [edit] and explain properly how to use your code and more importantly, explain how it works

Comment: @PieterGoosen I hope my new edit fulfills explanation part.